# Twitter Bootstrap: issue with img with class responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with a img with class "img-responsive".

Please see the picture

[image]

This is an image that ends precisely, but at different zoom levels img-responsive seems to "cut" several pixels of the image.

Do you have some idea? Workaround, for the moment, create with photoshop some transparent px on bottom....

Answer (score 0):

Your image and div height is not same. for example:

Your image div area `height:200px;` and your image `height:204px;` if you use div height like this your problem come.

Use same height div and image

*Not: In order to provide better information to share code here.*